# Is “query” a reserved name in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I encountered this strange behavior of MongoDB v2.0.7 when I was trying to use `query` as a key name for a reference field.

If I insert a record with a reference field named `query`, MongoDB fails to retrieve the object:

```
> db.item.insert({query: {$ref: "query", $id: ObjectId("50361887352fc04c86af4c10")}})
> db.item.find({query: {$ref: "query", $id: ObjectId("50361887352fc04c86af4c10")}})
>
```

But, if I change the name of the field to `query_`, everything is fine:

```
> db.item.insert({query_: {$ref: "query", $id: ObjectId("50361887352fc04c86af4c10")}})
> db.item.find({query_: {$ref: "query", $id: ObjectId("50361887352fc04c86af4c10")}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("503619f0dd2290f4bb17a275"), "query_" : { "$ref" : "query", "$id" : ObjectId("50361887352fc04c86af4c10") } }
```

It is also fine if the field has a simple non-compound value:

```
> db.item.insert({query: ObjectId("50361887352fc04c86af4c10")})
> db.item.find({query: ObjectId("50361887352fc04c86af4c10")})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50361b44dd2290f4bb17a276"), "query" : ObjectId("50361887352fc04c86af4c10") }
```

Am I missing something, or is this a MongoDB bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are undocumented reserved field names. I ran into [the same issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6078).

Comment: Thank you. This is a pretty annoying bug. I am using MongoEngine and it took me one day to figure out the cause of the problem.